# How can I get all the benefits of restarting my computer without actually rebooting it?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, memory, reboot

There are a lot of different reasons why a reboot would be beneficial for the system (like flushing RAM), and all the applications that might be running for a while. However, if we wanted to get to a reboot state without actually performing a reboot, what would it take (eg: applications to kill, delete temp files, clear cache, etc)?

I'm currently on GNU/Linux but would be interested to know for any operating system.

Comment: This is a pretty big ask.  It would vary quite a bit based on the architecture, and what applications are installed / running at the time.  Certainly more than I'm capable of helping with I'm afraid.  Good luck!

Comment: What is preventing you from restarting. Restarting is a huge amount less work that what you are asking for. I have never seen that done.

Comment: Everyone's "reboot state" will vary, you'd have to define yours pretty specifically. Or maybe break up the question into separate questions? You mention flushing RAM, caches, temp files, etc. I was going to vote to close, but I see the new contributor icon :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and yes, completely new at this! I figured it was going to be a very involved process but wanted to know if it was at all possible, and if there were maybe tricks to get it close to that state minus the specific apps that are running

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Unix/Linux based operating systems do great without rebooting often. Windows is the one that starts to act weird if it's left running for too long.

The most beneficial reason for restarting is, it is sometimes required to fully complete some sort of update or installation. Presumably because it needs to update something important that can't be done on the fly, without something crashing.

I'm also not an Operating System programmer. Someone who is could give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Both Windows and Linux need to be restarted for major updates. My Windows 10 Desktop runs 7x24 non-stop and then restarts as needed for updates

Comment: "Windows is the one that starts to act weird if it's left running for too long."  What?  I have Windows machines that go months without a reboot and work just fine.  The longest uptime machine I have ever worked on was a Windows machine that ran for 13+ years without a reboot.

Comment: Windows won't go 13 years without reboot unless you turned all updates off and left it in an entirely insecure state. However it will run long periods of time without acting weird - I agree with that.

Comment: @John - I routinely configure systems which have 21+ day uptimes.

Comment: So do I. My desktop runs 24x7 but I reboot it normally on Patch Tuesday

Comment: I was actually curious as to why some of these updates or installations required a reboot at all and if it would be possible to adjust files manually to get to the same effect. For example, I had trouble formatting a USB because apparently I needed to reboot the system which was odd to me because it's an external drive